# Recurly authentication error

Tags: java, recurly

im using Recurly client maven dependency and im getting error in the recurlyclient.java

the error says that

> "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder.setMaximumConnectionsPerHost(I)Lcom/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder"

this is regarding recurlyClient.open()

Please help me with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a version mismatch of the `async-http-client` library.

What's the version of the `async-http-client` that's available to you at runtime?  The `setMaximumConnectionsPerHost(int)` the method in [v1.8.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/async-http-client/1.8.0/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClientConfig.java#AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder.setMaximumConnectionsPerHost%28int%29) (and the versions prior) was renamed to `setMaxConnectionsPerHost(int)` in [v1.9.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/async-http-client/1.9.0/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClientConfig.java#AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder.setMaxConnectionsPerHost%28int%29).

So your code or a certain version of some library that you use is coded to work with `v1.8.0` or less of `async-http-client`, but at runtime you have the `v1.9.0` of it available to you instead. Look at your Maven dependency tree to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but on changing the version to 0.2.4 of recurly-java-library with async-http-client-1.7.20, im getting the following error.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912924/recurly-thowing-exception-when-using-with-google-app-engine